# S4 class in R for matrix

Tags: r, matrix, r-s4

This is a follow-up question to a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176763/r-function-to-create-band-matrix).

I need to write an `initialize()` method for a S4 class (named `Band`) that expects a matrix and a value for `k`. It should be defined as a function with formal arguments `(x, k)`, and should put the lower triangular elements of `X` into the object.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion is to read the manual and/or some of the fine tutorials available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org).  [This introduction to s4](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Genolini-S4tutorialV0-5en.pdf) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: `initialize` methods are pretty tricky; maybe you really want to write a constructor `Band <- function(x, k) { <...> }` that calls `new("Band", slotA=<...>, slotB=<...>)` or perhaps a `coerce` method using `setAs`.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143611/sources-on-s4-objects-in-r

Answer (score 1):

The Matrix package has many examples of matrix-related S4 classes and methods:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/

Download the source and check it out.